# How to make youtube video streaming player in windows forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, video, youtube

I am trying to make a youtube url streamer application in **windows form application** using **c#.net**.

I am able to play local videos using windows media player (COM COMPONENT) in built in visual studio.

But I am not getting how to stream url (youtube address) in windows media player. If there is any other better way please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add toolbox item by right clicking on any control -> choose item -> COM component -> Shockwave Flash Object, Drag and drop Shockwave Flash Object control on your form, paste YouTube URL to movie property of Shockwave Flash Object control, But don’t forget to delete “watch?” and “=” From URL , For example if YouTube video URL is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwkO4-s3OQ0 then remove watch? and then replace = sign with / sign, so URL will become http://www.youtube.com/v/zwkO4-s3OQ0
That’s it.