# YouTube videos in Shockwave Flash Object

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube, axshockwaveflash

Today I tried embedding a youtube video in my application using the Shockwave Flash Object control.

I followed the steps provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473755/how-to-make-youtube-video-streaming-player-in-windows-forms), but doing this led me to an error, saying that "Flash-embedded videos are no longer supported, but you can still watch this video on YouTube.".

My question is not how to make it work with a different control, but if it's actually still possible to do it with this control and if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: It sounds like YouTube have explicitly disabled this capability and it won't work anymore.

Comment: Flash is dead, don't try to revive it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Embeded Videos in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749984/youtube-embeded-videos-in-winforms)

Comment: also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982